# Assume $\arctan$ is differentiable. Prove that $\arctan(x) =1-x$ has a solution in $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $\arctan$ is differentiable. Prove that $\arctan(x) =1-x$ has a solution in $(0,1)$. The hint given is to use the intermediate value theorem (IVT).

> I do not understand how to show there is a solution using the intermediate value theorem. Could I get help to better understand how to apply IVT in this case?

Comment: Let $f(x) = (1-x)-\arctan x$. Note that $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = -{\pi \over 4}$. So the IVT implies that there is some $x \in (0,1)$ where $f$ 'crosses over'.

Comment: Please have a post self contained, so include the question in the post and not just the title. Also it would be nice to spend some time learning to use MathJax. A tutorial can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function

> $$ f(x)= \arctan(x)+x-1 $$

and see this $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1) =\pi/4$ which implies there is a point $x\in (0,1)$ where $f(x)=0$ (by IVT) that gives you

$$ \arctan(x)+x-1 = 0 $$

has a real root.

Comment: @scieice is that all i have to say?

Comment: Yes that's all what you need to do. What you have been asked is to prove that the eq. $\tan^{-1}(x)=1-x  \iff \tan^{-1}(x)+x-1=0 $ has a real zero and we have done it. Go back the theorem and read it carefully. Good luck.

Comment: sorry to ask u again hw can i prove there is'nt a second solution by a contradiction using rolle's theorem ?

Comment: You have been asked to prove that there is a solution but you have not asked to prove it is unique. However if you want to prove uniqueness then do more studies on the function. By the way do you know how to accept answers?

Comment: ok thank you alot  helped more than enough

Comment: Science's answer and comments gave all the required. If you want to prove that is is unique, you could easily write the derivative of $f(x)$ which is always positive whatever $x$ could be. So, whichever could be the range, $f(x)=0$ has only one solution.